# Necessity of curly braces for one-statement Unit functions

Tags: scala, return-type

I'm learning Scala and noticed that it is sometimes preferred, stylistically, that single-statement functions are not enclosed by curly braces. To that end, I ran some experiments:

**Experiment #1:**

```
def func1(v: Vector[Int]) =
  for {n<-v; if n % 2 == 0 && n % 3 == 0 } yield n

val v = func1((1 to 10).toVector)
println(v)
```

The function body is a single expression, which happens to be a comprehension. No curly braces or return type specification needed. Code compiles and produces the output `Vector(6)`.

**Experiment 2:**

```
def func2(s:String) =
  s + s

val s = func2("str")
println(s)
```

Again, a single expression. No curly braces or return type specification needed. Code compiles and produces output `strstr`.

**Experiment 3:**

This is where things get tricky:

```
var accum = "Begin "
def func3(arg:String)
    accum += arg // Cannot resolve symbol arg
```

Code won't compile, showing an error of `Cannot resolve symbol arg`. Clearly, Scala cannot tell that the line `accum += arg` is meant to be the body of `func3`, which, naturally, returns `Unit`. Either one of the following are acceptable fixes for the compiler:

```
def func3(arg:String){
    accum += arg
}
func3("End")
```

This fix applies curly braces. Code compiles, producing output `Begin End`.

```
def func3(arg:String): Unit = 
    accum += arg
func3("End")
```

This fix does not apply curly braces, but specifies `func3`'s return type. Code compiles, producing the exact same output.

So what's going on here? Why is it required that a `Unit`-returning single-statement function cannot be syntactically abbreviated?

Comment: U missed the `=` on your first attempt at expt 3, intentional?

Comment: Go through spec for clarity: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters

Comment: Procedure syntax is deprecated anyway. So just use `def func3(arg: String): Unit = accum += arg`.

Answer (score 1):

From scala spec

> Scala is a line-oriented language where statements may be terminated by semi-colons or newlines. A newline in a Scala source text is treated as the special token “nl”
>   if the three following criteria are satisfied:
>
> ```
> The token immediately preceding the newline can terminate a statement.
> The token immediately following the newline can begin a statement.
> The token appears in a region where newlines are enabled.
> ```

In the case of

```
def func3(arg:String)
    accum += arg
```

all three of the conditions are satisfied.

Go through [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters) to see full details.

Comment: Thank you. There's one thing here that's rather perplexing. Clearly, from the Scala spec, a closing parenthesis can terminate a statement, and `def func3(arg:String)` involves one such closing parenthesis. However, the statement itself leads to non-compilable code. Just open up a Script and attempt to compile the code `def somefunc(arg:String)`. You will find out that the compiler expects to see a `=` but it does not. Therefore, while I do understand that the closing parenthesis terminates a statement, for statements that begin with `def` there should be an exception, no?

Answer (score 0):

As @Karthik mentioned in a comment, I had neglected the `=` in **Experiment 3**'s first approach. Furthermore, @johny pointed me to the scala specification and I determined that even for single-statement functions or methods, either a pair of curly braces or a `=` will be absolutely required to make the compiler understand that we are defining a method.